# MyBatis does not support "javaType" property

Tags: mybatis

**The problem**

When insert a "TUserSession" instance via "TUserSessionMapper", "alwaysLoginFlg" and "alwaysLogoutFlg" fields' types are decided as "java.lang.Object". Not "..enums.CommonFlag".

1. org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.class in mybatis-3.5.5.jar ← **No javaType info**
   [image]
2. org.apache.ibatis.builder.SqlSourceBuilder.class in mybatis-3.5.5.jar ← **javaType decided as Object**
   [image]
   [image]
3. EnumValueTypeHandler.java ← **So I can't handle it**
   [image]

**Question**

1. How could I set the javaType properly?

There's no method with 'javaType' so I can't fix TUserSessionDynamicSqlSupport.java
[image]
**My Codes**

I used STS4 and MyBatis Generator 1.4.0 from Eclipse Marketplace

1. Table definition (PostgreSQL)

```
create table if not exists t_user_session (
    ...
    always_login_flg int not null,
    always_logout_flg int not null,
    ...
);
```

2. generatorConfig.xml

```
<generatorConfiguration>
    ...
    <context id="context1">
        <table tableName="t_user_session">
            <columnOverride column="always_login_flg"
                javaType="io.github.donggi.reminder.enums.CommonFlag"
                typeHandler="io.github.donggi.reminder.enums.EnumValueTypeHandler" />
            <columnOverride column="always_logout_flg"
                javaType="io.github.donggi.reminder.enums.CommonFlag"
                typeHandler="io.github.donggi.reminder.enums.EnumValueTypeHandler" />
        </table>
    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

3. TUserSession.java ← javaType applied well

```
package io.github.donggi.reminder.dto;

import io.github.donggi.reminder.enums.CommonFlag;

public class TUserSession {
    ...
    @Generated("org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator")
    private CommonFlag alwaysLoginFlg;
    @Generated("org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator")
    private CommonFlag alwaysLogoutFlg;
    ...
}
```

4. TUserSessionDynamicSqlSupport.java ← **javaType really applied??**

```
package io.github.donggi.reminder.mapper;

import io.github.donggi.reminder.enums.CommonFlag;

public final class TUserSessionDynamicSqlSupport {
    ...
    @Generated("org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator")
    public static final class TUserSession extends SqlTable {
        ...
        public final SqlColumn<CommonFlag> alwaysLoginFlg = column("always_login_flg", JDBCType.INTEGER,
                "io.github.donggi.reminder.enums.EnumValueTypeHandler");
        public final SqlColumn<CommonFlag> alwaysLogoutFlg = column("always_logout_flg", JDBCType.INTEGER,
                "io.github.donggi.reminder.enums.EnumValueTypeHandler");
        ...
    }
}
```

5. EnumValueTypeHandler.java

```
package io.github.donggi.reminder.enums;

@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.INTEGER)
public class EnumValueTypeHandler<T extends Enum<T> & EnumValue> extends BaseTypeHandler<EnumValue> {

    private final @NonNull Map<Integer, T> map;

    public EnumValueTypeHandler(@NonNull Class<T> type) {
        this.map = EnumUtil.asMap(type.getEnumConstants()[0]);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found that when convert POJO to SQL, there's no need of "map" field...

```
package io.github.donggi.reminder.enums;

@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.INTEGER)
public class EnumValueTypeHandler<T extends Enum<T> & EnumValue> extends BaseTypeHandler<EnumValue> {

    private final @NonNull Map<Integer, T> map;

    public EnumValueTypeHandler(@NonNull Class<T> type) {
        if (type.getEnumConstants() == null)
            this.map = null;
        else
            this.map = EnumUtil.asMap(type.getEnumConstants()[0]);
    }
    ...
}
```

It worked... Thank you.